# Whether dispose is called automatically by GC when not explitly called?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, disposable

I have DisposableObject is IDisposable. I know that it should be wrapped to the using or dispose is explicitly called.

```
public void Method()    
{
       var disposable = new DisposableObject();
}
```

But I have argued about this logic with some colleagues.
Do you think that 'unhanled' Dispose method will be called on automatically by GC on some point?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It will be called when the object is dereferenced from all sources and the GC makes its next round.

Comment: **No**, it'll call destructor (**finalizer**) not your Dispose() method. Inside finalizer usually implementations call the Dispose() method (if they follow Dispose pattern).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel no, it won't call the Dispose() method but the finalizer (there implementation _may_ call Dispose())

Comment: No. You should read about `Finalizer` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx

Comment: Microsoft strongly recommends your finalizer call Dispose: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspx

Comment: read [this great answer about `IDisposable`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/538238/571637) several times... know it, love it, live it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is in this case Dispose method will be called automatically by GC?

**No.** It will not call `Dispose` you have to call it yourself or use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) block which will ensure its disposal even in case of an exception.

```
using(var disposable = new DisposableObject())
{
  //your code
}
```

`IDisposable` is used to ensure that unmanaged resources held by the application are released prior to garbage collection. Since `GC` can't release resources held by unmanaged resources like file handler.

Answer (score 1):

No the GC does not call Dispose on disposable objects (objects implementing IDisposable).  The GC manages object clean up by calling the finalizer (destructor) of managed objects.
You implement a Dispose method if you want control **when** manage resources are freed (not if they are freed or not).

E.g If you have a class that has a TCPClient member then this is a managed object that controls a resource - the port its connected on.  If you dont implement IDispose on your class and you use an instance off it then at some point when the GC sees the TCPClient is no longer used it will finalize that object and the port will be close - but you have no control over WHEN that will happen.  If you need access to the port and a particlar time then you need to CONTROL WHEN its closed - in this case you can impliment IDispose and use a using statement or call Dispose directly yourself to ensure the resouce (port) is freed.

Comment: Just for clarity, for this to be true you must call `Dispose` in the finalizer: "If you don't implement IDispose on your class and you use an instance off it then at some point when the GC sees the TCPClient is no longer used it will finalize that object and the port will be close"

Answer (score 1):

If a class overrides a method called `Finalize` and an instance of that class is found to have been abandoned without `GC.SuppressFinalize()` having been called upon that instance, the GC will store a reference to the object in a list of things whose `Finalize` should be run ASAP (temporarily resurrecting it) and mark the object so that the next time it's abandoned it will simply disappear.  If any objects have been placed on the list for immediate finalization, the GC will then launch a thread to run their `Finalize` methods.

For whatever reason, the creators of C# decided to confuse things a little bit by forbidding programmers from overriding `Finalize` directly and instead requiring that programmers wishing to override `Finalize` use a construct they call a "destructor", with syntax reminiscent of a C++ destructor, but totally different semantics.  Although C# adds a little bit of wrapper code, one can generally think of `~className {whatever}` as being roughly equivalent to overriding `Finalize`.

Microsoft recommends that if one overrides `Finalize` (or implements a C# destructor), that override/destructor should simply call a method with signature `void Dispose(bool)`, passing `False` for the parameter value.  It based upon that advice that people get the idea that the GC calls `Dispose`.  Note that the GC *itself* doesn't call `Dispose`; note further that most objects *shouldn't* implement C# destructors nor override `Finalize` in any other way.  Unless one understands all the corner cases involved with `Finalize`, it's generally better to ensure that `IDisposable.Dispose` gets called *before* objects are abandoned.